# AngularJS: set default selected option via value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to change what option is selected in a  menu, by **value**.

**Example:**

HTML

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="myController">
        <p>n_images = {{n_images}}</p>
        <select data-ng-model="n_images">
            <option data-ng-selected="{{o.value == n_images}}"
                    data-ng-repeat="o in n_images_options" 
                    value="{{o.value}}">{{o.text}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.n_images = 4;

        $scope.n_images_options = [
            {value: 1, text: "1 image"},
            {value: 2, text: "2 images"},
            {value: 3, text: "3 images"},
            {value: 4, text: "4 images"},
            {value: 5, text: "5 images"},
            {value: 6, text: "6 images"},
            {value: 7, text: "7 images"},
            {value: 8, text: "8 images"}
        ];
    }
]);
```

This works using AngularJS 1.1.5 ([JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/billb123/wpwz2qbf/3/)).

However, it does **not** work in newer versions of AngularJS, such as
version 1.4.6 ([JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/billb123/v31eesj1/1/)).

How do I change what option is selected by using a value?  I'm trying to create a select menu that will be initialized by a query string value from the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best results you need to use `ng-options`:

```
<select data-ng-model="n_images" ng-options="o.value as o.text for o in n_images_options">
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eywLkdub/

Comment: Thanks!  This worked, though I ran into another issue that I was able to solve but don't understand - when using $location.search() to get n_images from the query string and add it to the $scope so that the select menu is selecting the right option, this only worked if I used parseInt() to convert n_images to type integer (I'm assuming it was type string).

Comment: as far as I know you'll have to use` ui-router` to make it so you don't need to `parseInt`: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing